# JPA Criteria Query - How to Avoiding Duplicate Joins

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteriaquery

I need to make a criteria query with a lot of conditional joins and where clauses, in such cases the code  tends become complex and could be produces duplicate joins.

For instance i have the following structure of Tables and JPA entities :

```
ACCOUNT
      ACCOUNT_ID
      ACCOUNT_TYPE


PERSON
      NAME
      AGE
      ACCOUNT_ID ( FK TO ACCOUNT ) 
      ADDRESS_ID ( FK TO ADDRESS ) 

ADDRESS
      ADDRESS_ID
      LOCATION
      COUNTRY
```

So assuming that i m using static metamodel implementation for applying criteria queries.

This is example of a wrong code that can generate duplicate joins:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Account> cq = cb.createQuery(Account.class);

    cq.select(accountRoot).where(
     cb.and(
      cb.equal(accountRoot.join(Account_.person).get(Person_.name),"Roger"),
      cb.greaterThan(accountRoot.join(Account_.person).get(Person_.age),18),
      cb.equal(accountRoot.join(Account_.person)                                   
              .join(Person_.address).get(Address_.country),"United States")
      )
     )

     TypedQuery<Account> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
     List<Account> result = query.getResultList();
```

The code above will generate a SQL with mutiples joins of the same table :

```
 Select
        account0_.account_id as account1_2_,
        account0_.account_type as account2_2_
    from
        account account0_
    inner join
        person person1_
            on account0_.account_id=person1_.account_id
    inner join
        address address2_
            on person1_.address_id=address2_.address_id
    inner join
        person person3_
            on account0_.account_id=person3_.account_id
    inner join
        person person4_
            on account0_.account_id=person4_.account_id
    inner join
        person person5_
            on account0_.account_id=person5_.account_id
    inner join
        address address6_
            on person5_.address_id=address6_.address_id
    where
        person3_.name=?
        and person4_.age>18
        and address6_.country=?
```

A simple solution is to keep instances of the Joins to reuse in multiples predicates like it :

```
   Root<Account> accountRoot = cq.from(Account.class);
   Join<Account,Person> personJoin= accountRoot.join(Account_.person);
   Join<Person,Address> personAddressJoin = accountRoot.join(Person_.address);

   cq.select(accountRoot).where(
     cb.and(
      cb.equal(personJoin.get(Person_.name),"Roger"),
      cb.greaterThan(personJoin.get(Person_.age),18),
      cb.equal(personAddressJoin.get(Address_.country),"United States")
      )
     )
```

Ok , it works , But with a real complex code with several tables and conditional joins for the codes tends to turn a Spaghetti code ! Believe me !

What is the better way to avoid it ?

Comment: You have multiple joins in the SQL because your code has many redundant calls to `join`. What did you expect would happen? Call `join` once for each join you actually need, and reuse the returned `Join` instance. You already created the two `Join` instances you need - just use them!

Comment: @Rob Sorry, tx for your comment, I just posted incomplete question yesterday, I fixed it.    I know that it was wrong , In my first experience with criteria query and joins I made ​​that mistake and i should have posted the two codes wrong and fixed. Question Fixed !  However I dont think that answer is wrong, It is just a suggestion for avoid it in a complex criteria query, i have a good experience with this strategy in my job, so i want to share this solution, but ok, if it is your opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A suggestion for avoid it is to use a builder class to encapsulate the joins , see below.

```
public class AccountCriteriaBuilder {

        CriteriaBuilder cb;
        CriteriaQuery<Account> cq;

        // JOINS INSTANCE
        Root<Account> accountRoot;
        Join<Account,Person> personJoin;
        Join<Person,Address> personAddressJoin;

        public AccountCriteriaBuilder(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            this.cb =  criteriaBuilder;
            this.cq = cb.createQuery(Account.class);
            this.accountRoot = cq.from(Account.class);
        }

        public CriteriaQuery buildQuery() {
            Predicate[] predicates = getPredicates();
            cq.select(accountRoot).where(predicates);
            return cq;
        }

        public Predicate[] getPredicates() {

           List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

           predicates.add(cb.equal(getPersonJoin().get(Person_.name), "Roger"));
           predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(getPersonJoin().get(Person_.age), 18));
           predicates.add(cb.equal(getPersonAddressJoin().get(Address_.country),"United States"));

           return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
        }

        public Root<Account> getAccountRoot() {
            return accountRoot;
        }

        public Join<Account, Person> getPersonJoin() {
            if(personJoin == null){
                personJoin = getAccountRoot().join(Account_.person);
            }
            return personJoin;
        }

        public Join<Person, Address> getPersonAddressJoin() {
            if(personAddressJoin == null){
                personAddressJoin = getPersonJoin().join(Person_.address);
            }
            return personAddressJoin;
        }


}
```

The “ace in the hole”  is the lazy loads for each required join instance, it will avoid duplicate joins and also to simplify the navigation process.

Finally, just call the builder like below :

```
AccountCriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = new AccountCriteriaBuilder(em.getCriteriaBuilder());
TypedQuery<Account> query = em.createQuery(criteriaBuilder.buildQuery());
List<Account> result = query.getResultList();
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: For see it running i have complete sample implementation of it with H2 in memory database and embeded jetty..  Just clone and run 

https://github.com/dufabricio/hibernate-sample

Comment: I guess I don't get it. Your "simple" solution is 8 lines of code. Your Builder solution is something like 30 lines of code to do the same thing. You cannot justify this unless the extra complexity can be pulled into a base class that is used by many entities or is amortized over many different queries. In my opinion, using a pattern for the sake of using a pattern is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Ok I agree ! this sample code is not the real spaguetti code, i just create a sample for explain.. it is not the real case.. 
But, well pointed @Rob i will try to make a sample more similar with my real code for justify it better..
it is the awesome part of internet.. Freedom of Speech !

Comment: I did have some moments in my life that i thought a lot about these concepts , Patterns, anti patterns, etc..  For me, today.. the apps must works fine. .just it !  ;) .. Again it is just my opinion.. !  thanks again by contribute with yours !  You comments shows me that this sample is not so clear.

Comment: Is there a way to force `Fetch` to reuse existing join?

Answer (score 12):

We use the following utility method to avoid duplicate joins

```java
public class CriteriaApiUtils {
  public static <X, Y> ListJoin<X, Y> join(Root<X> criteriaRoot,
                                             ListAttribute<? super X, Y> attribute,
                                             JoinType joinType
  ) {
    return (ListJoin<X, Y>) criteriaRoot.getJoins().stream()
        .filter(j -> j.getAttribute().getName().equals(attribute.getName()) && j.getJoinType().equals(joinType))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(() -> criteriaRoot.join(attribute, joinType));
  }
}
```

Comment: I used something similar - it is much less invasive that creating a builder and can be re-used for any type of criteria query.

Comment: It's simple and effective!

Comment: How do you use it ? Could you please share an example ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, I know, but maybe someone can help, since it took me quite a while to find a solution to this problem.

Straight to the point. I took the solution proposed by **user1096250** and simplified it a bit to fit my needs:

This method is the final method, expressed in generic form:

```
public Join<X, Y> getJoin(Root<X> root, String attribute, JoinType joinType) {
    return (Join<X, Y>) root.getJoins().stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getAttribute().getName().equals(attribute) && r.getJoinType().equals(joinType))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> root.join(attribute, joinType));
}
```

And this is the implementation. For example, this is a spec with between of my spec class for my entity CasoDeNegocioEntity

```
public Specification<CasoDeNegocioEntity> specifPc_fechaCumplimiento(LocalDateTime fechaInicio, LocalDateTime fechaTermino, String operador) {
    switch (operador) {
        case "between":
            return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
                    criteriaBuilder.between(getJoin(root, "plazosCumplimientoEntity", JoinType.INNER).get("fechaCumplimiento"), fechaInicio, fechaTermino);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In short, what this does is that it evaluates existing joins. If it exists, it returns the first one it finds, if it doesn't exist, it creates it. This avoids duplicate "inner join" and therefore duplicate rows in the result. And of course, it is no longer necessary to use the DISTINCT clause.

Thanks to all for the help. With this post more this [blog](https://reflectoring.io/spring-data-specifications/), I learned a lot about Specifications. Greetings!

Comment: In general, that is not required to use explicit `inner join` for `@XXXToOne` associations, just write `root.get(attributeName)` and `Hibernate` will do the magic - it "caches" inner joins acquired via `get` method. In case of outer joins that is clear that attempting to combine them may cause wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're doing complicated queries which combine fetch and join it is good to check both collections:

```
public static Join<?, ?> join(Root<?> from, String property, JoinType joinType) {
    return from.getJoins().stream()
            .filter(j -> j.getAttribute().getName().equals(property) && j.getJoinType().equals(joinType))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> from.getFetches().stream()
                     .filter(j -> j.getAttribute().getName().equals(property) && j.getJoinType().equals(joinType))
                     .map(f -> (Join)f)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElseGet(() -> from.join(property, joinType)));
}
```

First we check joins collection and then we also check fetch collection. This way we assure table is joined only once in a final SQL query.

Usage is following:

```
join(queryRoot, 'joinedProperty', JoinType.INNER);
```